# How can I mark a goal as completed inside a file in C#?

Tags: c#, file

I am making a program that allows the user to set different type of goals: Simple goals, eternal goals and checklist goals and store them in a file to load it any time. Then the user can record an event, that means that the user can mark a goal as completed and the program has to show this: [x] beside the goal indicating is completed. Like this:

```
[x] Play the guitar 10 minutes
[ ] Clean my bedroom 
[ ] Study for one hour
```

When you complete a goal the program gives you points. Simple goals must be marked, eternal goals don't have to be marked and checklist goals have be marked after you complete them certain amount of times.

I already made the other functionalities of the program such as: set a goal, store the goals in a file, load them from that file, etc. The problem is: when I record an event my program marks all my goals as completed but it just has to mark one goal at a time, not all of them because you haven't record it.

This is the for loop that I made to show the goals from the file, select one of them, assign the points to the general score and mark goals as completed inside the file:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(goal._dataFile);
                
Console.WriteLine("The goals are: ");
Console.WriteLine(" ");

int numIndex = 1;

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string [] parts = line.Split(",");
 
    string goalName = parts[2];

    Console.WriteLine($"{numIndex}. {goalName}");
    numIndex += 1;
}

string ans = Console.ReadLine();
int ansInt = int.Parse(ans);
Console.WriteLine(" ");

string lineSelected = lines[ansInt - 1];
string[] strings = lineSelected.Split(","); 

string points = strings[3];
int pointsInt = int.Parse(points);

Console.WriteLine($"You earned {points} points");

goal.SetPoints(pointsInt);

if (strings[0].Contains("Simple")) 
{
    string fileContent;

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(goal._fileName))
    {
        fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
                    
    string markedContent = fileContent.Replace("[]","[x]");

    // Write the modified content back to the file
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(goal._fileName))
    {
         writer.Write(markedContent);
    }
}
```

Just to make it clear I have two files: One stores the the data the user can see and the other stores almost the same data but separated by commas and the points assigned to the goals.

Please help.

Comment: What’s the specific problem?

Comment: If I want to record just one goal as completed the program doesn't mark only that goal, it marks all of them even if I don't record it. I want it to mark only the goals I record except the eternal goals.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at this line:

```
string markedContent = fileContent.Replace("[]","[x]");
```

This command will mark all the goals as completed. You should iterate through fileContent to find the correct string (with id = ans as I understood) and update just this one string.